# Объект дате выводит число и дату от чего зависит?

Tags: javascript

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 2);

function getDateAgo(date, days){
   date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    return date

}

console.log(getDateAgo(date, 1));
```

Выводит дату

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 2);

function getDateAgo(date, days){
  return date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    

}

console.log(getDateAgo(date, 1));
```

Выводит число миллисекунд

Comment: В первом случае вы возвращаете из функции объект типа `Date`, а во втором - то, что возвращает метод `setDate()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А что Вы ожидали увидеть?

Метод [date.setDate](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp) возвращает миллисекунды, представляющие получившуюся дату

> Return Value: A Number, representing the number of milliseconds
>   between the date object and midnight January 1 1970

результат его работы Вы вернули из функции , а затем вывели в лог.

В первом же случае вернули сам обьект date и вывели его в лог.